# Define range as all data in coumn A on Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is I want to define the range as all the data in column A on sheet2. The code below displays the data from column A of the active worksheet. I've also tried Sheet2.Range and this does not work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim i As Single
Dim c As Range           

ManufacturersList.Clear 'Make sure the Listbox is empty

i = 1


For Each c In Sheets(2).Range("A1", Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    ManufacturersList.AddItem Cells(i, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the cells in Sheet2 but ignoring the reference you're creating in the actual [.AddItem method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277575.aspx).

```
For Each c In Sheets(2).Range("A1", Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    ManufacturersList.AddItem c.Value
Next
```

When you referenced `Cells(i, 1).Value` it was using the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as the parent of `Cells`.